# How to Compare Dates based on Years in two different columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've been trying to figure out how to compare the dates based on Years in two different columns of the same Worksheet. Columns 'S' and 'U' have dates in the format of - mm/dd/yyyy. The problem seems to be probably just in assigning date to the variable 'date1' and 'date2' but, there could be more problems in the code.

```
Function Condition()

Dim j As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wb As Worksheet
Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date


Set wbk = Application.Workbooks("RELIEF VALVE MASTER SPREADSHEET.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wbk.Worksheets("Valve List")

lastrow = ws1.range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For j = 2 To lastrow

date1 = ws1.Cells(j, 18).Value
date2 = ws1.Cells(j, 20).Value

If Year(date1) = Year(Date) - 1 Or Year(date2) <> Year(Date) - 1 Then
    Application.Workbooks("MaxiTrak RV Service Report - Blank.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ML_PSV_SERVICE").Select
    Cells(j, 7).Value = "Routine"
Else
    ws1.Cells(j, 7) = ""
End If
Next j

End Function
```

The basic Idea behind this code is to check if cell in the same row Ex:(S2 and U2) have the same year or not. If they are in the same year i.e(2018) then insert text "Routine" into another open Workbook on Column #7 in the same row. Thanks for the help in advance.

The Error -> Type Mismatch on `date1 = ws1.Cells(j, 18).Value`

[Proof that it is a date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxUed.png)

Comment: What is actually going wrong? Is the comparison in your `If` statement not working expected, are you getting an error, etc.?

Comment: What is `temp1`?  Also, you are comparing to `year(date)` this is the current date.  Should it just be `if year(date1)<>year(date2) then`?

Comment: Is temp1 the name of a sheet?

Comment: I edited my question for better help. The date is supposed to be the previous year and not the current year.

Comment: @Snehill the error you show does not seem to appear in the code at all....

Comment: I don't know why it still shows an error for me? any suggestions?

Comment: @BigBen yes It still shows an error.

Comment: Because your dates are probably not dates but perhaps "text-that-looks-like-dates." Can be confirmed looking a screenshot of your data. Btw, this can be done with a formula, just want to confirm that you need VBA for this.

Comment: Ahh, now you have edited the error to match the edited code...

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry about that.

Comment: @BigBen Yes It is supposed to be done in VBA

Comment: Column S is column *19*. You have text in column 18, hence the type mismatch. Column U is column *21* as well.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks a lot. That worked, I was actually not considering the hidden columns in the sheet. Although, there are 2 another problems. The Word "Routine" is being pushed to the other Workbook but it does not take filter into consideration uses all the data unfiltered. Secondly, even when the data is filtered through the VBA code the word "Routine" is being pushed out in the entire column on unfiltered data.

Comment: A loop by row (`For j = 2 To lastrow`) will not ignore rows that are filtered out... I'd post a new question - it's best to keep it to one issue per question, and we've fixed the main issue here.